# Want to use Wild Card for declared variable in Case statement

Tags: sql, string, where-clause, sql-like

"AND" is in where clause of the query

Trying to use the Like operator in the "else" part

```
AND TCD.ANI = Case when @CallerID is null then TCD.ANI Else  @CallerID end
```

Comment: There is no `LIKE` or wildcard in your code, which makes your question unclear about what you want to do.

Comment: That's what i am looking for.
Syntax that how the wild card will be added in the "else" part for declared variable

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
AND (@CallerID is null OR TCD.ANI LIKE @CallerID)
```

I don't see many cases where `CASE` comes handy in conditions. Usually, things are simpler expressed with boolean logic.

Maybe you want to concatenate wildcards to the variable as well. In standard SQL, using string concatenation operator `||`:

```
AND (@CallerID is null OR TCD.ANI LIKE '%' || @CallerID || '%')
```

Comment: 1) CallerID is the number which will be passed from the front end of the report.
Let's say if the user passes the null value from the front end, i want the report to ignore the callerID and fetch the report.
2) But if the CallerID is passed by the user & that ID is not complete, lets say that the actual ID was 01234 but the user passes 1234 for that purpose i using like operator in else part but unable to find the syntax
First point is working but not the second one

Comment: @GhiasAhmed: then the second expression does what you  ask for.

Comment: That's what i am looking for. Syntax that how the wild card will be added in the "else" part for declared variable